# RadListView with both scrolls (horizontal and vertical)

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to implement a grid with both scroll, horizontal and vertical (think of a tv guide for example). Rendering with a simple GridLayout doesn't work, it's too slow. So I tried to move everything to a RadListView (virtualization is the key here, plus the 'load more feature')

The page is currently working with two ScrollView and some StackLayouts and GridLayout. Trying to put those inside a RadListView doesn't work, I get only the vertical scroll (and my parent horizontal ScrollView gets ignored completely).

TNS Android/iOS Version: 6.0.2

NS - Angular Info:

```
"@angular/animations": "~8.2.0",
"@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~8.2.0",
"@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.0",
"@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
"nativescript-angular": "~8.2.0",
"nativescript-orientation": "^2.2.4",
"nativescript-permissions": "^1.3.8",
"nativescript-ui-listview": "^7.1.0"
"tns-core-modules": "~6.0.0"
```

**Expected result**: handle both scroll in a single RadListView component.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do it with just RadListView. May be you could try rendering multiple RadListView, one for each horizontal lane stacked inside vertical ScrollView.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried, but I cannot scroll each horizontal lane individually,
I'll try with a scroll tracking to the other lanes and check performance. Thanks again Manoj!

Comment: You should be able to scroll each horizontal lane individually, if you find issues please share a minimal Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.